How to make different channels in the same process use different ports to send data to the same service address？
I created two channels to send messages to the same server address, but only one TCP connection was created.
I tried SetInt(GRPC_ARG_USE_LOCAL_SUBCHANNEL_POOL, 1); but it doesn't work.
according to Port seems to be shared between to separate grpc channels in same process
Is there really no way to help me achieve it?
Client code segment:
  // target_address_ = "127.0.0.1:9506"
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_INITIAL_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 50);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_SEND_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 1024 * 1024 * 10);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 100);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_USE_LOCAL_SUBCHANNEL_POOL, 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    channels_.push_back(grpc::CreateCustomChannel(
        target_address_, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(), channel_args));
    stubs_.push_back(MessageReceivalHandlerService::NewStub(channels_[i]));
  }

The result of listening to port 9506, only one tcp connection.
enter image description here

What do you hope to gain by using multiple connections?

The server side and client side are deployed on two machines. If the connection does not receive a message for more than 300ms, the processes on the two machines will exit, which is not what we want. Recently, I found that GRPC_CHANNEL_TRANSIENT_FAILURE often occurs in the connection between Client and Server. The conversion time from GRPC_CHANNEL_TRANSIENT_FAILURE to GRPC_CHANNEL_READY exceeds 300ms, so I am trying to solve this problem by establishing multiple channels. When one channel does not work, quickly use another channel for information exchange.

Why would a transient failure only affect a single TCP connection if everything else is the same?

I don’t know if it will affect all tcp connections, so I want to try whether establishing multiple channels can achieve my purpose.
